# jquery select new element outside of this.parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<tr>  
    <td class="schedule-available" style="background-color: rgb(255, 128, 128);"> 09:00 AM - 01:00 PM
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs viewOrder" type="button">ViewOrder</button>
   </td>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <td class="sm-fnt lastName-holder">Last name: </td>
</tr>
```

Currently with my code `$(this).parent()` is referring to the first `<tr>` what I'm trying to do now is also find the `<td class="sm-fnt lastName-holder">` to be able to change the text from last name to something else; please keep in mind I have multiple lists like this, so that's why I need to use `$(this).parent()`.

I've tried the following:

```
 $(this).parent().next('.lastName-holder').html('test');
 $(this).closest('tr').next('.lastName-holder').html('test');
```

But neither works.

Comment: $(this).parent() referring to first `tr` ?

Comment: yes because i need to update something in there too then i need to go to the next tr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `$(this).closest('tr').next().find('.lastName-holder').html('test');`

Comment: By any chance do you know what to do if there where multiple <tr><td class=''> to update i though it would work for all

Comment: Why are you retaining the call to `parent()` when you're using `closest()`?

Comment: yes, @DavidThomas is correct, you can remove `parent()` from the statement.
@Yeak to change text in all `td`s with class `lastName-holder`, you can try this: `$(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('td.lastName-holder').html('test');`

Comment: no sorry i know im chaing the question a bit but if i have multiple <tr><td> with different class so for example <tr><td class='lastName-holder'></td></tr> then i have <tr><td class='firstname-holder'></td></tr>